# How To Exclude Some Fields From Array of Nested Objects In spring boot using mongotemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

```java
public class DemoClass {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Long cts;
    private Long mts;
    private boolean favourite;
    private String createdBy;
    private String modifiedBy;
    @DBRef
    private List<NestedClass> list_of_it;
    @DBRef
    private List<Test> tests;
    private List<String> order; // An ordered list of the request ids

    
}
```

```java
public class NestedClass {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Long cts;
    private Long mts;
    private boolean favourite;
    private String createdBy;
    
}
```

**Expection**  When I send a get request to query all DemoClass I want to exclude all the fields other than id and name from NestedClass. We should have arrays of NestedClass.

I tried projection and aggregation but no able to find that particular solution.

Comment: Please explain `if (this.requests != null && this.requests.size() > 0 && this.requests.get(0) == null) `  

Comment: comparing `this.requests.size()`  to 0 is considered bad practice, better : `requests.isEmpty()` (or not;).. so you replace your "collections" with empty ones..*only*, when they are not null *and* not empty *and* the first element is null ... sounds wrong

Comment: Based on your description, it sounds like [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) may be an approach worth pursuing. What issues did you run into with them?

Comment: It's a list of nested class and inside the Test class again there is list of nested class I want to exclude some fields from Nested class from every where it's present.